# Deploy SSIS-Package with PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, ssis, ssms

I'm trying to deploy an .ispac-file via PowerShell to SQL Server (2017). So far I have already downloaded the SQL Server PowerShell Module and of course SSIS is installed as well (Version 15.0.2000.93).

The PowerShell script I'm trying to run is pretty much the same as the one from the documentation:

```
# Variables
$SSISNamespace = "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices"
$TargetServerName = "name"
$TargetFolderName = "name"
$ProjectFilePath = "path"
$ProjectName = "name"

# Load the IntegrationServices assembly
$loadStatus = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SQLServer.Management.IntegrationServices, "+
    "Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL")

# Create a connection to the server
$sqlConnectionString = `
    "Data Source=" + $TargetServerName + ";Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
$sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $sqlConnectionString

# Create the Integration Services object
$integrationServices = New-Object $SSISNamespace".IntegrationServices" $sqlConnection

# Get the Integration Services catalog
$catalog = $integrationServices.Catalogs["SSISDB"]

# Create the target folder
$folder = New-Object $SSISNamespace".CatalogFolder" ($catalog, $TargetFolderName,
    "Folder description")
$folder.Create()

Write-Host "Deploying " $ProjectName " project ..."

# Read the project file and deploy it
[byte[]] $projectFile = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($ProjectFilePath)
$folder.DeployProject($ProjectName, $projectFile)
```

The error occurs on line 18:

```
$integrationServices = New-Object $SSISNamespace".IntegrationServices" $sqlConnection
```

and says that the assembly or a dependency of it can't be found (see below):

> "Microsoft.SqlServer.Dmf.Common,Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"

Also, when I try 'Start PowerShell' by rightclicking on the Integration Services Catalog in SSMS(18.5), I get the error:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: value(mscorlib)

I don't know if the errors are connected in some way, but I hope it helps finding the problem.
I ran the PowerShell as administrator and there are no restrictions to reading or executing DLLs.

Thanks alot in advance and I'm happy with any hints you can give me!

Comment: Check your output/$loadStatus. It seems curious that you ask for the v14 assemblies but the Dmf error references v13. Otherwise, verify you have sufficient permissions in the database, run the PS as an admin user

Comment: Thanks @billinkc I haven't thought about outputting before... §loadStatus does contain v13 although it shouldn't, that's strange. There shouldn't be any problem with permissions neither as I usually deploy packages with the SSIS wizard, but I'd like to automate things so I need PS to work. I already ran PS as admin. But thanks for your comment, guess I'll have to dig deeper.

Comment: The output takes me to a folder that contains v11, v12 and v13 of the Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.dll, but v14 is missing. When I change the version in $loadStatus to one of the three other versions the error doesn't change though.